# Помощь с Pascal ABC

Tags: pascalabc.net

моя подруга 9-классница получила задание по информатике на дом, а именно написать программу на Pascal ABC. 
Условие звучит так: 
 Уличный продавец газет получает а рублей с продажи каждой из 50 газет. С продажи каждой из последующих газет он получает на 20% больше. Разработайте программу, которая вычислит заработок продавца, если он продаст за день 200 газет. Используйте файлы input.txt и output.txt для ввода и вывода данных.

Я сделал программу, которая просто вычисляет заработок продавца и выводит полученные данные в консоли, но как работать с вводом и выводом данных я не знаю.

Программа выглядит так:

```pascal
    Var  
    A:real;  
    k:integer;  
    Begin  
    Write('Стоимость одной газеты: ');ReadLn(A);  
    Write('Количество газет: ');ReadLn(k);  
    if k <= 50 then WriteLn('Заработок продавца: ',k*A,' руб.')  
    else WriteLn('Заработок продавца: ',(A*((k-50)*1.2+50)):0:2,' руб.')  
    End.
```

Comment: Стоит, во-первых дать вопросу нормальное название, а во-вторых убрать из него все лишнее.

Comment: Какое название ты считаешь нормальным?

Comment: Вот смотрите, ваш вопрос какой? - как работать с вводом и выводом данных. А конкретнее - как читать данные из файлов и записывать в них. Согласны?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с текстовыми файлами на начальном уровне понадобится связка:
-  переменная типа `TextFile`   (далее `f`)
- `AssignFile(f, имя)`
- `Reset/Rewrite` (для ввода и вывода соответственно)
- `Readln/Writeln` c первым аргументом `f`
- `CloseFile`

В данном случае формат подразумевается жёсткий - например, в первой строке цена, во второй количество. В общем случае же чтение может идти до конца файла с проверкой вроде `while not EOF(f)`

[Пример](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=840)